# Node.js server.close() won't close due to active connection

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to show some information before the application is closed. So, I create an event that will be fired when the server receive a `SIGINT`. This code will work if no connection is ever made. However, if there had been a connection `localhost:4040`, the server will never close as the server think there is still an active connection(connection count will be 1). The part I don't understand is why Node.js still think there is an active connection when the request has already finish. Is there any ways to kill a connection or my current way of closing the request is wrong?

Here is the code of What I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var http = require('http')

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.end('test');    
}).listen(4040);

process.on( 'SIGINT', function(){
  server.getConnections(function(err, count){
    console.log('connection:' + count);
  })

  server.close(function(){
    process.exit();
  });
})
```

Some ideas I have:

1. saving a copy of the sockets I receive and close them individually

Hope someone can give me some advice in solving this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. store all sockets from you have and close them manually
2. use process.exit() and destroy the entire process instead
3. use domains and do a scary deprecated domain.dispose()